# SQL Query Confused

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

Display:

- account no.
- customer id
- initial amount in terms of [lakhs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system) (rounded off to 2 decimals) [change the column heading to 'INITIALAMTIN_LAKHS']
- amount category(amt < 50000 show as 'Low', amt > 5000000 as 'High', otherwise, 'Medium') [change the column heading to "AMOUNT_CATEGORY"]
- start date
- maturity date (use term in months to calculate it) [change the column heading to "MATURITY_DATE"]

of all 'ACTIVE' (upper case) FD accounts which were started after year 2004.

This is what i have written so far

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NO, CUST_ID, ROUND(INITIAL_AMT,2) AS INITIALAMTIN_LAKHS, 
CASE 
    WHEN INITIALAMTIN_LAKHS<50000 THEN 'low'
    WHEN INITIALAMTIN_LAKHS>5000000 THEN 'High'
    ELSE 'Medium'
END 'AMOUNT_CATEGORY',
START_DT, FROM BANK_FD_ACCOUNT;
```

cannot understand further

Table i:

```
BANK_FD_ACCOUNT
(
  ACCOUNT_NO, 
  CUST_ID, 
  START_DT, 
  FD_TERM_MNTH, 
  INITIAL_AMT, 
  ACC_STATUS 
)
```

Comment: You cannot use INITIALAMTIN_LAKHS in your case statement - repeat the calculation instead.

Comment: BTW confused??.

Comment: Oh and remove the comma after start_dt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT account_no, 
   cust_id, 
   ROUND(initial_amt/100000,2) AS initialamtin_lakhs, 
   CASE 
        WHEN initial_amt < 50000 THEN 'Low' 
        WHEN initial_amt > 500000 THEN 'High' 
        ELSE 'Medium' 
   END as amount_category, 
   start_dt, 
   ADD_MONTHS(start_dt, fd_term_mnth) AS maturity_date 
   FROM bank_fd_account 
   WHERE UPPER(acc_status) = 'ACTIVE' AND TO_CHAR(start_dt,'YYYY') > 2004
```

Comment: This works Maturity date ADD_MONTHS(start_dt, fd_term_mnth)

Answer (score 1):

Hoping `INITIAL_AMT` is actually the amount, and not in lakhs or millions or anything like that, then you need to change it into hundreds of thousands:

```
SELECT
    ACCOUNT_NO, 
    CUST_ID, 
    ROUND(0.00001 * INITIAL_AMT,2) AS INITIALAMTIN_LAKHS, 
    case 
        when INITIAL_AMT<50000 then 'Low'
        when INITIAL_AMT>5000000 then 'High'
        else 'Medium'
    end as AMOUNT_CATEGORY,
    START_DT
from 
    BANK_FD_ACCOUNT
where
    ACC_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' and
    START_DT >= '20150101'
```

No idea what maturity date or how to use term in months to calculate it.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say MATURITY_DATE is `add_months(start_dt,fd_term_mnth)`. That's if `start_dt` is a `date` and `term_mnth` represents the term of the loan or whatever this thing represents, in months.

Answer (score 0):

An example of a valid query...

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NO
     , CUST_ID
     , ROUND(INITIAL_AMT,2) INITIALAMTIN_LAKHS
     , CASE WHEN ROUND(INITIAL_AMT,2)  <   50000 THEN 'low'
            WHEN ROUND(INITIAL_AMT,2)  > 5000000 THEN 'High'
            ELSE 'Medium'
       END AMOUNT_CATEGORY
     , START_DT
  FROM BANK_FD_ACCOUNT;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alter session SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';  
select ACCOUNT_NO,CUST_ID,
CASE
WHEN ROUND(INITIAL_AMT*0.00001,2)>FLOOR(ROUND(INITIAL_AMT*0.00001,2)) THEN 
TO_CHAR (ROUND(INITIAL_AMT*0.00001,2),'0.99')    
ELSE TO_CHAR(ROUND(INITIAL_AMT*0.00001,2))   
END as INITIALAMTIN_LAKHS,   
CASE  
WHEN INITIAL_AMT<50000 THEN 'Low'  
WHEN INITIAL_AMT>500000 THEN 'High'  
ELSE 'Medium'  
END as AMOUNT_CATEGORY,  
START_DT,  
ADD_MONTHS(START_DT,FD_TERM_MNTH) as MATURITY_DATE  
from BANK_FD_ACCOUNT   
where UPPER(ACC_STATUS)='ACTIVE' and TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(START_DT,'yyyy'))>2004;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select account_no,  
cust_id,   
CASE  
WHEN ROUND(INITIAL_AMT*0.00001,2)<1 THEN   
TO_CHAR (ROUND(INITIAL_AMT*0.00001,2),'0.99')      
ELSE TO_CHAR(ROUND(INITIAL_AMT*0.00001,2))     
END "INITIALAMTIN_LAKHS",   
case  
when initial_amt < 50000 then 'Low'  
when initial_amt > 5000000 then 'High'  
else 'Medium'  
end "AMOUNT_CATEGORY",  
To_char(start_dt, 'dd-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),  
To_char(add_months(start_dt,fd_term_mnth),'dd-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as MATURITY_DATE  
from bank_fd_account  
where acc_status='Active'   
and To_char(start_dt,'YYYY')>'2004';
```